# how can i display values on emulator?

Tags: android-emulator

I am newbie to android.
I'm working on a project that measures execution time of applications.
It is printed on logcat but I want to print it on emulator screen.
Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean you want to display on the application screen?
You can do that by simply writing a text view at the position of the view where you intend to display and set the text with the value.

Snippet:
Add to layout at a desired position:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/perf_value"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

In your activity, set the value that you are say you are displaying on LogCat

```
TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.perf_value);
tv.setText(perfParamIntendToDisplay);
```